# Expose Http Response time in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-component

Is there any way to get the response time of an endpoint in MULE?
Example is the Http Connector in mule, I need to get the response time of the invoked endpoint.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little further your use case? You want to get it from a component?

Comment: hi @JuanAlbertoLópezCavallotti, I would like to get the response time of the endpoint in fulfilling the request, example the http endpoint would connect to http://google.com/, I would like to get the time elapsed for the request. HttpConnector might have field or data for response time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using Mule Server Notification.

There is an interface MessageProcessorNotificationListener which can listen to PRE/POST invoke of a message processor.

I have achieved to get the response time of an message processor using the following code.

```
  long startTime;
 if (m.getAction() ==  MessageProcessorNotification.MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_PRE_INVOKE) 
 {
     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 }
 if (m.getAction() ==     MessageProcessorNotification.MESSAGE_PROCESSOR_POST_INVOKE) 
 {
     long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
     AbstractEndpoint ep = (AbstractEndpoint) proc;
     log.info("Http call to : "+ ep.getName() + " took " + executionTime + "ms response time");
 }
```

Here is the response

Http call to : endpoint.http.google.com.80 took 224ms response time.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need to leverage to take some statistics around the endpoints are server notifications, please see the following documentation page:

https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications

Check out the endpoint notification.

Comment: your right notification is a way to do this, I have referred to this http://huksley.blogspot.com/2014/10/mule-business-event-logging-via.html. The problem now is how to acquire the statistics for the message processor.