# MuleESB | Obtain time taken in HTTP connector

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el

I'm using Mule 3.6.1 CE and need to get the total time taken within a HTTP Connector. I'm currently doing so by setting a counter before and after the request but it's feels like there should be a better way. Maybe a property of the inboundProperties?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it just for logging purpose?

Comment: Yes but for every message rather than just to debug. We process 30m requests a day so I need it to be lightweight.

Comment: if you log in `debug` mode, it gives timestamp for inbound and outbound request

Comment: Cool, I'll take a look and check the performance.

Comment: I was able to achieve this here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579852/expose-http-response-time-in-mule-esb

Comment: Great, thanks everyone we've got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up `http` logs at `debug` level in your `log4j2.xml` should log the `inbound` and `oubound` `payload` along with `timestamp`

```
 <!-- Http logs -->
 <AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger" level="DEBUG"/>
```